# Downsizing From a Cage to Racks

Tags: server-room

When moving from a cage to racks at a datacenter, what is some equipment I might need.  I have already thought about pull-out monitor/keyboard and IP KVMs.  What else might I need?  Also, how do you store the extra stuff such as network cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use cable management accessories, such as the cleaning-brush lined openings above AND below rack mount switches, and other pieces to support and wrap cables on.

What else? Most vendors make industrial sized power strips that fit on the back of their racks. You can buy shelves for non-rack equipment, and blanking panels, front and rear, for airflow management.

For your hottest and densest racks, APC makes an air evacuator that replaces the rear door. It draws air in and vents it upwards, either through a hose out of the room (through the ceiling) or into your A/C intake. It can make a BIG difference in racks that are recirculating their own hot air.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, how do you store the extra stuff such as network cables?

We simply use metal rackmount storage drawers. No particular vendor. Google will deliver.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm opening a can of worms regarding proper cooling, but in some of my less-dense racks I leave blank spaces between servers.  If there's no ventilation on the top or bottom of the particular servers I store my spare parts in the blank spaces.